# Deep-linking implementation in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am implementing Deep-linking in my android application. I have added the properties mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) but still I am not getting any logs while debugging neither its working for my application.
My manifest is looking like:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <data android:host="domain" android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="domain" android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I am testing on a device having api level 23. But still its not working. Any help will be really appreciated.

I have placed following file on my server:
I have created a directory named ".well-known" and then saved the file having content given below with name "assetlinks.json"

```
 [{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target" : { "namespace": "android_app",
  "package_name": "package-name",
  "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["fingerprints"] }
}]
```

But still neither getting any logs, nor its working.

Comment: You are setting `<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">`, but haven't mentioned if you also took the steps necessary to [declare website associations](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc)

Comment: Please have a look on updated question. I have mentioned about the file I have placed on my server.

Comment: Hmm. Not seeing anything immediately. Try going through [this guide](https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-deep-linking-android-app-links) with a fine-toothed comb to see if any steps were missed when setting up.